# Styling img tag's alt text in IE, works fine in chrome and FF

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer

None of the font styles are working for img tag in IE 11, the same styles work fine in chrome and FF.

See fiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/mjth0fo6/

```
   <img alt="Some text I want styled" />

   img {
     font-size: 30px
   }
```